# Calling a function in a screen from another screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this complex screen/navigation structure in my app.

there is a tabbed screen with two tab views.==> TabScreen(a default tab controller) has TabView1Screen and TabView2Screen.

TabScreen has a function(lets say LoadData() ) which when app loads it calls an api and the responses are fed to both TavView1 and TabView2 screens.

the TabView1Screen has a button option when on click I take the user to another SelectionScreen and to a SubmitScreen. (these navigations happen in root level. not inside the tab view).

after SubmitScreen there's a thank you screen. and after there I pop up all the screens up until the user is visible with TabView1Screen again.

at this moment I  need to call LoadData() so the whole two TabView screens are fed with the new set of data from the api call.

how can I achieve this in flutter. ? please help me with something.

Edit.
I need to pass some parameters to LoadData() as well. For now im passing them as a json request body.

**The TabbedScreen**

```
//the future for Future Builder in build body
Future<DataList>? dataFuture;

//I call this in initState()
init() async {
    data = {
      "key": value,
      "key": value,
      "key": [],
      "key": [],
      "key": []
    };
    dataFuture = getLists(data);
}

//in future builder after loading finished I set the tab views
Widget _tabSection() {
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabCtrl,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            MapScreen(
              markersSet: _markersSet,
            ),
            ListScreen(markersSet: _markersSet),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
//markerset is the result from getLists(data) function
```

**The TabView1Screen**

```
//this screen is with a google map view. 
//so there are few pins on the map. 
//when tapping a one. I give a bottom sheet like so with some info and buttons. 

generalSheet(BuildContext ctx, places.DetailsResult? result) =>
      showModalBottomSheet(
          useRootNavigator: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
          context: ctx,
          builder: (builder) {
            return Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 0.0),
              child: GeneralHighlightView(
                result: result,
              ),
            );
          });

//inside this GeneralHighlightView
//I have button options which take the user to a new screen SelectScreen ,(and closes this bottom sheet)

Navigator.of(context).pop();
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(selectUIRoute,
                arguments: SelectScreen(
                  args
                ));
          },

//form SelectScreen next to SubmitScreen and ThanksScreen. 
//then from ThanksScreen pops back to TabView1Screen
```

To Manage Api call functions I have a mixin class
**Mixin**

```
mixin FetchPins {


Future<MarkerList>? getPins(dynamic data) async {

//the api call with http
//this returns a set of lists as a result. 
}
```

The function I need to call from TabView1Screen is.

```
getLists(data)
```

With parameter data passed.

Comment: Can you add tabview, getData method and tab screen codes?

Comment: Can you submit some code?